# BLE interfce mac OS 10.12 class porting

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, kernel-extension

My job is to port BLE mouse (Bluetooth low energy mouse) class driver from Mac 10.10 to 10.12 ..

My old kext was derived from IOHIDEventDriver class. and provider class in info.plist is IOHIDInterfcae

When I am building above kext with 10.12 sdk , compilation is done, but while loading kext I am getting below error:

> The vtable '__ZTV15CbBLEInterface' is malformed. Make sure your kext has been built against the correct headers

Below is the output of `sudo kextutil -n -print-diagnostics myble.kext`

> Warnings: 
>       Dependency lacks appropriate value for OSBundleRequired and may not be availalble during early boot: 
>           com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily - Safe Boot
>           com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver - Safe Boot

Answer (score 0):

after updating the xcode with 8.2.1 , code compiled with correct headers and it worked :). Thanks to all of you for your help.